# Eclipse makefile only for C (windows version)

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

This Eclipse (Helios) is running on a Windows PC, crosscompiling for an ARM9 target board.

I can generate and run programs for the target using managed makefile option. both for Linux and  stand alone binary (using the cross-arm.gun plugin) No problem there.

However I want to try compiling using the makefile only option. I have done already this using WinArm, but I want to try with Eclipse.

However Eclipse gives me a  "Cannot run program "make": Launching failed" So it seems I need to provide Eclipse with a "make.exe" from somewhere. I know there is one under the Winarm folder, so I thought I'd ask here before I try that.

What is the normal way (if there is such a thing) for including a "make" into an Eclipse makeffile only configuration?

Thanks

Comment: Cross compiling on windows... Is there a reason you're such a masochist?

Answer (score 0):

[MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) provides a build of make which Eclipse is happy to work with.

Make sure its directory is in your PATH.